# Generating all subarrays from an array of Integer

Tags: swift

I want to generate all the subarrays from an array of integer as below:

```
func subarrays(_ arr: [Int]) -> [[Int]]{
    var result = [[Int]]()
    guard arr.count >= 1 else { return [arr] }
    for i in 0..<arr.count {
        for res in result {
            var resi = res
            resi.append(arr[i])
            result.append(resi)
        }

        result.append([ arr[i] ])
    }
    result.append([])
    return result
}

subarrays([1,2]) //{},{1,2},{1},{2}
subarrays([1,2,3]) //{} {1}{2}{3}{1,2}{2,3}{1,3}{1,2,3}
```

I have alternative implementations, but really want to know if it is acceptable to use

```
for res in result
```

while adding to the array, or whether this would be seen as unusual practice in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your immediate question: Yes, it is fine to mutate an array while enumerating its elements. The reason is that

```
for res in result { ... }
```

is equivalent to

```
var iter = result.makeIterator()
while let res = iter.next() {
    // ...
}
```

and that arrays are *value types* in Swift: Mutating `result` inside the loop creates a new value and does not affect the original array that the iterator is using. See [Remove element from collection during iteration with forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37997465/1187415) on Stack Overflow for more details.

There are some possible simplifications. Here

> ```
> var resi = res
> resi.append(arr[i])
> result.append(resi)
> ```

is is not necessary to declare another array variable, this can be shortened to

```
result.append(res + [arr[i]])
```

A better name for the `res` variable might be `subarray` or `subset`.

Instead of looping over the array indices

> ```
> for i in 0..<arr.count {
>     // ... do something with `arr[i]` ...
> }
> ```

you can enumerate the array (as you already do in the inner loop)

```
for elem in arr {
    // ... do something with `elem` ...
}
```

The

> ```
> guard arr.count >= 1 else { return [arr] }
> ```

is not needed. Your algorithm already does “the right thing” for an empty array.

So this is what we have so far:

```
func subarrays(_ arr: [Int]) -> [[Int]] {
    var result = [[Int]]()
    for elem in arr {
        for subarray in result {
            result.append(subarray + [elem])
        }
        result.append([elem])
    }
    result.append([])
    return result
}
```

It becomes a bit simpler if `result` is not initialized with an empty list, but with a list containing the empty subset. Adding the array element itself, and the empty set at the end of the function is no longer necessary:

```
func subarrays(_ arr: [Int]) -> [[Int]] {
    var result: [[Int]] = [[]]
    for elem in arr {
        for subarray in result {
            result.append(subarray + [elem])
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

(The subset are returned in a different order now, though.)

The inner loop could be replaced by a *map*  operation:

```
func subarrays(_ arr: [Int]) -> [[Int]] {
    var result: [[Int]] = [[]]
    for elem in arr {
        result.append(contentsOf: result.map { $0 + [elem] })
    }
    return result
}
```

or even the entire function body replaced by a single expression:

```
func subarrays(_ arr: [Int]) -> [[Int]] {
    return arr.reduce(into: [[]], { (result, elem) in
        result.append(contentsOf: result.map { $0 + [elem] })
    })
}
```

but that is a matter of taste – is not necessarily easier to read.

There is nothing particular with respect to integers in the algorithm, the function can be made generic to take arrays of any element type – or even arbitrary *sequences.*

Finally I would call it `subsets(of:)`, which is what the function computes:

```
func subsets<S: Sequence>(of seq: S) -> [[S.Element]] {
    var result: [[S.Element]] = [[]]
    for elem in seq {
        for subset in result {
            result.append(subset + [elem])
        }
    }
    return result
}
```